# Using an admin theme with an already installed theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

All,
I recently bought the following admin theme:
http://themeforest.net/item/white-label-a-full-featured-admin-skin/270758

I also already have the following theme installed and am using it on my website:
http://themeforest.net/item/alyeska-responsive-wordpress-theme/164366

I want to use some features of the first admin theme but not have any issues with the already existing themes that I have installed in Wordpress.

Does anyone know how to use an Admin theme and the features in it without affecting the current shortcodes, css, etc that I'm already using on my own site?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are no real WordPress admin themes. The dev cycle changes the admin styles and functions very regularly, with major changes every 3 months or so. This would break any admin themes and makes it a nightmare to maintain, thus no ones does it.

ps. You can change some basic styles like colors/logo and if you know what you doing a bit more. But the link you showed, there is no way, unless you plan on never updated your install , ever.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to tell you, but that admin theme you bought is not for WordPress.  It's meant to be an HTML start to a backend of a web application.

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, I'm not sure if you're meaning to take some things from the admin theme and using them in your WordPress theme. If so, please be sure to be more clear in your question as to what you want to do.

Comment: No, you're correct. I meant to see if I can use the admin theme as an admin theme in Wordpress. I'm not that familiar with an Admin theme so was trying to get information on how to use it and if the admin theme I purchased would do the trick.

Comment: Again, I'm sorry you ended up purchasing the theme without knowing this beforehand, but that particular item is not meant to be installed for use as a WordPress admin theme.